# How to use the fast ping with alot of ip addressess in cmd to send alot of packets for every hop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ping

**What have I tried**

I wanted to create a way to make a faster pinging method for cmd than the normal '-t' command. So I came up with an idea to make two files and link them together:

The first st1.bat file contains

```
ping 10.10.10.10 -n 1
st2.bat
```

And the second st2.bat file contains

```
ping 10.10.10.10 -n 1
st1.bat
```

This creates a loop so it goes on forever.
The '-n' command is the number of packets you send. So by sending just one packet and then opening the second .bat file makes it a lot faster (30 milliseconds).

The command for extracting just the IP addresses is:

```
(@for /f "tokens=8" %a in ('tracert -4 -d wikipedia.org^|find "ms"') do @echo start ping %a)>ips.txt
```

**What do I need**

I want to combine these two codes and make 2 files for each IP to create a loop just like I showed you above. Every IP loop should have its own cmd window because if everything is in one window every packet should wait for the previous one to be done:

And finally link all the files together in one .bat file that I think will look like that:

```
Start st1.bat
Start st3.bat
Start st5.bat
```

Comment: PS: This is just for a project not for illegal purposes.

Comment: What's wrong with `for /L %%I in () do ping 10.10.10.10 -n 1`?

Comment: @aschipfl This works but I need this for every IP from the hops

Comment: Well, if your IP addresses are in a file, put around a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to read them; if they are consecutive (like `10.10.10.1`, `10.10.10.2`, etc.) you could use another `for /L` loop to build them: `for /L %%J in (1,1,254) do echo 10.10.10.%%J`...

Answer (score -1):

Try to use: ping -n 1 -l 1 
if you doesn't want
Firing  with 1 bytes of data: try this command:
@echo off
:1
ping -n 1 -l 1  | find "TLL="
goto 1

Comment: This answer does not appear to be formatted, provides no explanation, and does not appear to address the requirement of continuous looping over multiple IP Addresses. I advise that you consider making improvements should you wish for it to remain acceptable.

Comment: @Compo look at his reputation. It's only 1! He know nothing about formatting or whatever. I think it's better to be kinder to new members.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi, look at the comment, it was more than a year ago. Now, take a look at the content of my comment, break it down, and tell me with full explanation, what about it is untrue or unkind. Just to let you know in advance, I disagree with your assessment, and my comment(s) to any response, whilst not intended, may cause you further distress.

Comment: @Compo I think we have different cultures and this cause the way we think to be different. In my country, when people want to talk to each other, they say the words in very carefully considered order, and sometimes indirect.

Comment: @Compo What you said is not something unusual for me (I'm about 3-4 years here), but I can remember when I was joined. This serious & professional atmosphere was somehow unfamiliar. For what you said to him, if I were you I would say something like: "please edit your answer and explain more. Then format it correctly. You can learn formatting from `stackoverflow.com/blablabla`."

Comment: @Compo I also suggested and edit but the queue was full. He had formatted his answer, but he didn't know for example for a new line he should press 2 <kbd>ENTER</kbd>s.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi, There's a toolbar in the answer boxout with buttons, and there's site help, should one or more of those be unfamiliar. Using it, to submit code, you would highlight the code, then press the `{}` button. So there's absolutely no need to understand HTML, markdown or anything like it, just to correctly post what was entered above. In addition to that, and more importantly, it does not answer the question posed. I would surmize that what's offered here was intended to be a comment, but due to their lack of site reputation, they decided to abuse the answer area to say their piece!